# Adding extra variables to a URL

Tags: javascript, php

Using JavaScript I managed to add a variable to a page and used $_GET on the new page to use the variable to perform queries. This first implementation worked fine as I was only using one variable. However I need to use two variables now and I'm running into some problems while doing it. If I combine both variables in the first page like shown below, the values are mixed up where my db value goes to my table id.

```
 window.location.assign("test.php?db=&tbl=" + yourDB);
```

I tried putting both IDs only in my new page and using reload as my DB value would already have been passed. Using

```
 window.location.reload("test.php?db=&tbl=" + yourTbl);
```

But this doesnt work either.

How can I get the url to have both my DB and table in the correct format? Like

```
test.php?db=test&tbl=customer
```

**EDIT**
`yourDB` variable is passed from a select form option from a different page which in turn opens the new page where the `yourTbl` variable exists.I can't therefore call `yourDb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.location = 'test.php?db=' + yourDB + '&tbl=' + yourTbl ;
```

'OP is asking: yourDB since this variable stores the values of select options from a different page.Any ideas'

My answer is 'Get value from selection menu list in the another page, and save this value into local storage or session storage.'

Something like this,

```
// save your db
window.sessionStorage.setItem("db", yourDB)
// get your db
var obj = window.sessionStorage.getItem("db");
```

Comment: I think that those variables need to be switched (`db=' + yourDB`) :)

Comment: Thanks for your response and the example.